# create a new column from a loop

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dataframe

I have a dataframe containing a  bunch of ip addresses and the date. I would like to create a new column indicating where these ip addresses are from i.e. country

the code that gives me the country is the following, but I would like to create a loop that replaces each id address in the line below and stores the result as a new column or a new list where I can append it to the df.

```
from ip2geotools.databases.noncommercial import DbIpCity
response = DbIpCity.get('40.77.167.144', api_key='free')
response.country
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

### Using `apply` and a `lambda` function

Let your DataFrame have a column 'IP', you can try the following:

```py
df['Country'] = df.apply(lambda row: DbIpCity.get(row.IP, api_key='free').country, axis=1)
```

### Example

```py
# Sample DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({'IP': ['40.77.167.144', '5.39.7.103']})

    IP
0   40.77.167.144
1   5.39.7.103
```

Result

```py
df['Country'] = df.apply(lambda row: DbIpCity.get(row.IP, api_key='free').country, axis=1)

    IP              Country
0   40.77.167.144   US
1   5.39.7.103      FR
```

Comment: thank you! this is exactly what I am trying to do, except that i get the following error:

Comment: InvalidRequestError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-35-20d1513d3e61> in <module>
----> 1 df['Country'] = df.apply(lambda row: DbIpCity.get(row.ip_address, api_key='free').country, axis=1)

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in apply(self, func, axis, raw, result_type, args, **kwds)
   6876             kwds=kwds,
   6877         )
-> 6878         return op.get_result()
   6880     def applymap(self, func) -> "DataFrame":
~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/core/apply.py in get_result(self)

Comment: My guess is that you may have invalid data in your dataframe. Could you provide a sample dataframe to try this ?